# capturing parentheses using regex on iphone

Tags: iphone, regex, ios

Trying to get the URL out of some HTML I'm parsing (on iPhone) using 'capturing parentheses' to just group the bit I'm interested in.

I now have this:

```
NSString *imageHtml;  //a string with some HTML in it

NSRegularExpression* innerRegex = [[NSRegularExpression alloc] initWithPattern:@"href=\"(.*?)\"" options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive|NSRegularExpressionDotMatchesLineSeparators error:nil];
NSTextCheckingResult* firstMatch = [innerRegex firstMatchInString:imageHtml options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [imageHtml length])];
[innerRegex release];

if(firstMatch != nil)
{
    newImage.detailsURL = 
    NSLog(@"found url: %@", [imageHtml substringWithRange:firstMatch.range]);
}
```

The only thing it lists is the full match (so: href="http://tralalala.com"  instead of http://tralalala.com

How can I force it to only return my first capturing parentheses match?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Regex groups work by capturing the whole match in group 0, then all groups in the regex will start at index 1. `NSTextCheckingResult` stores these groups as ranges. Since your regex requires at least one group the following will work.

```
NSString *imageHtml = @"href=\"http://tralalala.com\"";  //a string with some HTML in it

NSRegularExpression* innerRegex = [[NSRegularExpression alloc] initWithPattern:@"href=\"(.*?)\"" options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive|NSRegularExpressionDotMatchesLineSeparators error:nil];
NSTextCheckingResult* firstMatch = [innerRegex firstMatchInString:imageHtml options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [imageHtml length])];
[innerRegex release];

if(firstMatch != nil)
{
    //The ranges of firstMatch will provide groups, 
    //rangeAtIndex 1 = first grouping
    NSLog(@"found url: %@", [imageHtml substringWithRange:[firstMatch rangeAtIndex:1]]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need pattern something like this:

```
(?<=href=\")(.*?)(?=\")
```

Comment: This trick with the lookahead and back assertions works good. thanks. I'm still interested to know how to access the various groups one might indicate using parentheses (for instance if I specify 3 groups I'm interested in... how do I access these)

Comment: $1, $2, $3, etc. Still the whole match is accessible as a group $0. So in your case you need to retrieve $1 (first explicit group). $0 Would be the whole match. Lookahead and look behind are not exactly groups, you can't access them.